# Learning vba but not working

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am working in visual studio and writing according to

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kc1d337(v=vs.100).aspx

in the Form1_Load procedure.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     Dim anInteger As Integer = 42
     Dim aSingle As Single = 39.345677
     Dim aString As String = "I like candy"
     Dim aBoolean As Boolean = true      
            MsgBox(anInteger)
            MsgBox(aSingle)
            MsgBox(aString)
            MsgBox(aBoolean)
             }
```

and the I click F5 to run it but I get 38 errors?!?!

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1002  ; expected  Variables   c:\users\owner\desktop\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Variables\Variables\Form1.cs   22  Active

Comment: You've put VB code into a C# project.  And vba proably has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: Got it! I am just trying to learn :-). Sorry if my question was stupid.

Comment: Being this a simple error due to inexperience I recommend to delete the question and avoid downvoting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've accidentally created a C# project instead of a VB one.

Typical signs to look out for if you're writing quick bits of code in either VB or C# and I, err... someone, didn't pay attention, are braces (`{` and `}`, a.k.a. squiggly brackets) and the keyword `void` instead of `Sub`:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
```

as compared to the VB signatuer for the same method:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
```

As you haven't written much, the best course of action would be to go File->New->Project (discard the current one) and carefully choose "Visual Basic" under Templates, and you'll want a Windows Forms Application.

P.S. VBA is Visual Basic for Applications, which is a bit different from VB.NET.

Comment: Got it! I just want to learn one programming language to start with and I chose Visual basic since I have used it alot in Excel.

Comment: @Heresh; since you are starting learning a new programming language to code in Visual Studio, I've seen from many parts they recommend C# instead of VB.

Comment: Can I use C for Excel?

Comment: @Downvoter Please let me know what is wrong with that answer and I'll correct it, or you could propose an answer of your own.

Comment: @Heresh If you are writing script code directly inside Excel, that's indeed VBA, but it's not VBA what you posted here. VBA is more similar to VB.NET than to C#, but still quite different. So to make a suggestion what language you should learn, I might need a bit more context of what you are trying to achieve. Is your only goal some scripting in Excel? Or do you also want to learn a fully-fledged programming language on the way? Do you want to make this a profession on some point or just as a hobby?

Comment: I want to learn fully fledged programming to make it my profession

Comment: @Heresh Stack Overflow is not the place for discussions.